# Analyse existing codebase for localization readiness

Tags: module, template, internationalization, localisation, regex

I have a recollection of seeing a tool or script that could analyse a legacy Magento project (custom theme and modules) to check for non-i18n code.

The concept of a regex to find strings that are not double-underscore wrapped `__('abc')` crosses my mind but seems likely to get a lot of false positives.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I've developed [an extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/MagentoTranslationTool) that you can use to collect the texts that should be translated from a magento module (or a set of modules). It is based on the same regex used by the tool that [@Fooman talkes about in his answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8261/146).
It also let's you identify texts from a locale that are not translated (key = value) but for this false positives may occur.
The extension is free, give it a try. I've used it on my other custom modules and it seams to work.

Answer (score 1):

Magento once had a download in their Enterprise section called 'translation-tools' which gives you a bunch of scripts to create translation csv files. Maybe this is what you are recollecting?

The code uses regexes to find `__('abc')` but does not perform the reverse (finding strings that are not run through Magento's translations).

I would currently have to agree with the assessment that you would get a lot of false positives when trying to find this programmatically since you are parsing xml, html, php, javascript and potentially some sql for good measure.